# MVC create, edit, delete actions "Cannot implicitly convert type" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

I am going to create a delete button for my table

here is my code

```
<center>
    <H2>LIST OF REGISTERED STUDENTS</H2>
    <br /><br />
</center>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
           Last Name
        </th>
        <th>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;E-Mail
        </th>
        <th>
            Password
        </th>
        <th>
            Student Number
        </th>
        <th>
            &nbsp;Program
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.student_name)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.student_lname)
        </td>
        <td>
             &nbsp;&nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.student_email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.student_password)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.student_number)
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.student_program)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.student_name }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.student_name }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.student_name })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

but when I create the delete syntax

```
 public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            CSdbConnectionString db = new CSdbConnectionString();
            student student = db.students.Find(id);
            if(student == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(student);
        }

        // POST: Student/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            CSdbConnectionString db = new CSdbConnectionString();
            try
            {
                student student = db.students.Find(id);
                db.students.Remove(student);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("ViewStudents","ConsulSked");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

the code `db.students.Find(id)` has an error of

> Cannot implicitly convert type CS.Models.student to CS.student

here is my student class

```
  [Table("student")]
    public class student
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int student_id { get; set; }
        public string student_name { get; set; }

        public string student_lname { get; set; }

        public string student_email { get; set; }
        public string student_password { get; set; }

        public string student_number { get; set; }

        public string student_program { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my data context class

```
   public class CSdbConnectionString : DbContext
    {
        public CSdbConnectionString()
        : base("CSdbConnectionString")
        { }

        public DbSet<appointment> appointments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<faculty> faculties { get; set; }
        public DbSet<sched> scheds { get; set; }
        public DbSet<student> students { get; set; }
}
```

what should I do? I can't create the delete option.

Comment: The error makes it sound like you have two different definitions for the same class.

Comment: Besides David comment, you are passing student name to your action methods where you should actually pass the Id.

Comment: that's the only definition for my class student

Comment: which part moe? and where?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, for those in the future who will have the same error.

It is because I have a .dbml file in my project so I can store my stored procedures. That is the

> CS.student

the one in my namespace model is the

> CS.Models.student

and that's the one we need.

So instead of

```
student student = db.students.Find(id);
```

make it

```
CS.Models.student student = db.students.Find(id);
```